# Express server socket.io now getting 404 error

Tags: node.js, express, socket.io

I've looked at a few other similar issues, but none have helped me solve my problem.  I recently started some updates on a personal project of mine, and I ended up having to re-clone the repo after discovering it was not running online.  After running npm i to install my packages, it opens locally, but the console begins filling up with this error: http://localhost:3000/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=MWbrM4h 404 (Not Found)

I tried changing to listening on http or directly on io, based on other responses on here, but no changes.  Here's my code.

```js
const express = require('express'),

  massive = require('massive'),
  bodyPar = require('body-parser'),
  CombatCtrl = require('./Controllers/CombatCtrl'),
  AuthCtrl = require('./Controllers/AuthCtrl'),
  EnemyCtrl = require('./Controllers/EnemyCtrl'),
  path = require('path'),
  socket_io = require('socket.io'),
  sharedsession = require("express-socket.io-session");
require('dotenv').config();
const session = require('express-session')({
  secret: process.env.SESSION_SECRET,
  resave: false,
  saveUninitialized: true
});

const app = express()

app.use(bodyPar.json())

app.use(session)

app.use(express.static(`${__dirname}/../build`));

app.get('*', (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, '../build/index.html'));
});

const {
  SERVER_PORT
} = process.env

const server = app.listen(SERVER_PORT, () => {
  console.log('How do you want to do this?', SERVER_PORT)
})

const io = socket_io(server)

io.use(sharedsession(session, {
  autoSave: true
}));

io.on('connection', function(socket) {
      socket.emit('start', /*emit params sent as obj*/ )

 //I have stuff in here, but it 's irrelevant to the landing page 
    }
```

Comment: At which port the project is running. Try testing the socker.io module separately away from your project.

Answer (score 0):

try to do something like this.

```
const {
  SERVER_PORT
} = process.env

const server = app.listen(SERVER_PORT, () => {
  console.log('How do you want to do this?', SERVER_PORT)
})

const io = socket_io.listen(server)

io.on('connection', function(socket) {
   console.log('connected to socket');
})
```

Comment: Thanks guys, i think it was an issue with my dependencies. I pulled the project back down from the two on a new location, ran npm I and it's all working. I appreciate the help though.